# Ranking (with duplicates) of collection/array in php (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, collections

I built a collection with Laravel which outputs json. It's supposed to be a ranking with name, score and rank attributes. The scores are already sorted and they need their correct ranking. When 2 or more scores are the same, they should have the same ranking number and the one that comes next should have the next number.

Example:
Nick - 28 pts - 1
Sarah - 25 pts - 2
Bret - 22 pts - 3
Sofie - 22pts - 3
Justin - 20pts - 4
 etc

At the moment I have this result:

```php
{
    "data": [
        {
            "rank": 1,
            "name": "Jari",
            "score": 51
        },
        {
            "rank": 2,
            "name": "Kenny",
            "score": 50
        },
        {
            "rank": 2,
            "name": "Lisa",
            "score": 50
        },
        {
            "rank": 4,
            "name": "Sven",
            "score": 44
        },
        {
            "rank": 5,
            "name": "Laurens",
            "score": 37
        },
        {
            "rank": 6,
            "name": "Maxim",
            "score": 35
        },
        {
            "rank": 6,
            "name": "Kevin",
            "score": 35
        },
        {
            "rank": 6,
            "name": "Joachim",
            "score": 35
        },
        {
            "rank": 9,
            "name": "Geoffrey",
            "score": 19
        },
        {
            "rank": 10,
            "name": "Elke",
            "score": 8
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the function in my controller:

```php
  public function addRanks()
    {
        $scores = $this->makeCollection();
        $duplicateScores = $this->makeCollection();

        foreach ($scores as $key => $score) {
            foreach ($duplicateScores as $duplicateKey => $duplicateScore) {
                if ($score['score'] == $duplicateScore['score']) {
                    $score['rank'] = $key = $duplicateKey;
                    break;
                }
            }
            $score['rank'] = $key + 1;
        }
        return $scores;
    }
```

The `$key` variable should be stopping with counting, as I would expect, but it sadly doesn't. Does this code make sense or am I looking at this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If data in `$scores` is already sorted by score it could be like this

```
public function addRanks()
{
    $scores = $this->makeCollection();

    $rank = 1;

    $previous = null;

    foreach ($scores as $score) {
        if ($previous && $previous['score'] != $score['score']) {
            $rank++;
        }

        $score['rank'] = $rank;

        $previous = $score;
    }

    return $scores;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! Though I'm not sure what $item is doing there?

Comment: Sorry, it should be `$score`.

Comment: I get an error saying `Trying to access array offset on value of type null`. Is it because you declared `$previous` as null?

Comment: I found it. I declared `$previous = ["score" => 0];` so I didnt get the error. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Fixed, I changed default `$rank` to 1 and added `$previous` to the condition.